# How can i get this info like the mapbox provide?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I found this info from mapbox. How can I get the geometry type from a vector service source?

[image: Screenshot]

```
{
account: "wandergis",
tilesetid: ""
}
account:"***"
layers:[
{
 account: "***",
 tilesetid: "wandergis.37w768q3",
 layer: "putian", 
 geometry: "Point"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Every feature within a vector tile layer may have a different geometry type. There are two main ways of interacting with this data:

- using `$type` filters to show / hide features based on their geometry type https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#types-filter
- using `querySourceFeatures` to get a list of all visible vector tile features as GeoJSON features and checking their `type` property https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map#querySourceFeatures http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-objects